# Possible way to serialize an `externalptr` before saving?

Tags: r

Is it possible in R to register a function that is called before saving?

The purpose of this would be to serialize an external pointer before save is called or a session is quitted.

Comment: I suspect your best bet is to petition the package author(s) to implement said functionality with some sort of serialization on the Rcpp side.

Comment: I am the package author :), just want to skip on the overhead of serializing on every single call the user does.

Comment: Argh. Apologies. Just had this asked of the `triebeard` package, so I feel your pain. From TFM on `serialize` and `saveRDS`: _"The refhook functions can be used to customize handling of non-system reference objects (all external pointers & weak references, and all envs other than namespace & pkg envs and .GlobalEnv). The hook function for serialize should return a character vector for references it wants to handle; otherwise it should return NULL. The hook for unserialize will be called with character vectors supplied to serialize and should return an appropriate object."_

Comment: Sweet! That's exactly where I was looking for, couldn't find it.... guess should rtfm more than code ;)

Comment: @hrbmstr, might as well post as answer ...