# HTML pages not retained in list while using mclapply

Tags: r, web-scraping, doparallel, xml2

While using simply lapply read_html page results are retained.

```r
library(xml2)  

lapply(c("https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/datahack-radio-1-machine-learning-competitions-with-kaggle-ceo-anthony-goldbloom/","https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/datahack-radio-lyft-dr-alok-gupta/"), function(x){read_html(x)})
#> [[1]]
#> {xml_document}
#> <html>
#> [1] <head lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">\n<meta http-equiv ...
#> [2] <body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-45087 s ...
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> {xml_document}
#> <html>
#> [1] <head lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">\n<meta http-equiv ...
#> [2] <body class="post-template-default single single-post postid-46725 s ...
```

While using Parallel mclapply:

```r
library(xml2)
library(parallel)  

mclapply(c("https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/datahack-radio-1-machine-learning-competitions-with-kaggle-ceo-anthony-goldbloom/","https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/datahack-radio-lyft-dr-alok-gupta/"), function(x){read_html(x)}, mc.cores = 2)
#> [[1]]
#> {xml_document}
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> {xml_document}
```

I can't figure out why it's happening, even with foreach I'm not able to get the desired results as normal lapply. Help!

Comment: Since the `mclapply` executions are in parallel via forked processes, the external pointers returned by `read_html()` are lost (they can't be serialized). You'll need to use `as.character(read_html(…))` and then re-process the HTML content once the `mclapply` has finished _or_ do whatever processing you want to do on the HTML content inside the `mclapply` and return a data frame or list or (whatever) that can be returned without being lost.

Comment: @hrbrmstr could you please give me any thread so that I can dig in more to understand it in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Time to sew

(I mean, you used the word *thread* so I'm not passing up the opportunity for a pun or three).

Deep in the manual page for `?parallel::mclapply` you'll eventually see that it works by:

- forking processes
- serializing results
- eventually gathering up these serialized results and combining them into one object

You can read `?serialize` to see the method used.

#### *Why cant we serialize `xml_document`/`html_document` objects?*

First, let's make one:

```
library(xml2)

(doc <- read_html("<p>hi there!</p>"))
## {xml_document}
## <html>
## [1] <body><p>hi there!</p></body>
```

and look at the `str`ucture:

```
str(doc)
## List of 2
##  $ node:<externalptr> 
##  $ doc :<externalptr> 
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"

doc$node
## <pointer: 0x7ff45ab17ce0>
```

Hrm. Those are `<externalptr>` objects. What does `?"externalptr-class"` (eventually) say abt them?

```
…
"externalptr" # raw external pointers for use in C code
```

Since it's not a built-in object and the data is hidden away and only accessible via the package interface, R can't serialize it on its own and [needs help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843171/possible-way-to-serialize-an-externalptr-before-saving). (That hex string — `0x7ff45ab17ce0` — is the memory pointer to where this opaque data is hidden).

#### *"You can't be serious…"*

Totally am.

In the event you're from Missouri (the "Show Me" state), we can see what happens without the complexity of parallel ops and raw connection object serialization machinations by just trying to save the document above to an RDS file and read it back:

```
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".rds")
saveRDS(doc, tf)

(doc2 <- readRDS(tf))
## List of 2
##  $ node:<externalptr> 
##  $ doc :<externalptr> 
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
```

Now, you may be all like *"AHA! See, it works!"* Aaaaand…you'd be **wrong**:

```
doc2$node
## <pointer: 0x0>
```

The `0x0` means it's not pointing to anything. You've lost all that data. It's gone. Forever. (But, it had a good run so we should not be too sad abt it).
This [has been discussed by the `xml2` devs](https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+serialize+is%3Aclosed) and — rather than make life easier for us — they punted and made `?xml_serialize`.

#### *Wait…there's an `xml_serialize` but it's kinda not all that useful?*

Yep. And, it gets even <strike>better</strike> worse.

Hopefully your curiosity was sufficiently piqued that you went ahead and found out what this *quite seriously named* `xml_serialize()` function does. If not, this is R, so to find out just type it's name without the `()` to get:

```
function (object, connection, ...) 
{
    if (is.character(connection)) {
        connection <- file(connection, "w", raw = TRUE)
        on.exit(close(connection))
    }
    serialize(structure(as.character(object, ...), class = "xml_serialized_document"), 
        connection)
}
```

Apart from wiring up some connection bits, the *complex sorcery* behind this `xml_serialize` function is, well, **just `as.character()`**. (Kind of a let-down, actually.)

Since parallel ops perform (idiomatically) the equivalent of `saveRDS()` => `readRDS()` when you return an `xml_document`, `html_document` (or their `_node[s]` siblings) in a parallel apply you eventually get back a whole pile of nothing.

#### What can a <strike>content thief</strike> innocent scraper do to overcome this devastating limitation?

You are left with (at minimum) four choices:

- expand the complexity of your function in the parallel apply to process the XML/HTML document into a data frame, vector or list of objects that can all be serialized automagically by R so they can be combined for you
- be cool  and have one parallel apply that saves off the HTML into files (the HTTP ops are likely the slow bit anyway) and then a non-parallel operation that read them sequentially and processes them — which it looks like you were going to do anyway. Note that you're kind of being a leech and rly bad netizen if you don't do the HTML caching to file anyway since you're showing you really don't care about the bandwidth and CPU costs of the content you're <strike>purloining</strike> scraping.
- don't be cool by doing ^^  and, instead, use `as.character((read_html(…))` to return raw, serializable, character HTML directly from your parallel apply and then re-`xml2` them back in the rest of your program
- fork the `xml2` , layer in a proper serialization hack and don't bother PR'ing it since you'll likely spend alot of time trying to convince them it's worth it and still end up failing since this "`externalptr` serializing` is tricksy business, fraught with peril and you likely missed some edge cases (i.e. Hadley/Jim/etc know what they're doing and if they punted, it's prbly something not worth doing).

> In reality, rather than use `xml2::read_html()` to grab the content, I'd use `httr::GET()` + `httr::content(…, as="text")` instead (if you're being cool and caching the pages vs callously wasting other folks' resources) since `read_html()` uses `libxml2` under the covers and transforms the document (even if sometimes just a little) and it's better to have untransformed raw, cached source data vs something mangled by software that thinks its smarter than we are.

#### FIN

There really isn't any more I can do to clarify this than the above, verbose-mode blathering. Hopefully this expansion also helps others grok what's going on as well.